Does ST_Simplify help on lines?
I have a function that selects all lines whose geometry fall into given tile envelope.
There are a couple millions of lines with proper indices on the table.
Would the query perform better if I would precalculate ST_Simplify(line.geometry), have that value stored in a separate column in table and do ST_Intersect(simplifiedGeomColumn, envelope)?
Is that the usual practice for queries performance fine tuning?
PS.
I am aware of potential false positives/negatives but I am not concerned about them atm.

Try it on a subset of you table

Without trying I guess that the effect would not be big. The first step of st_intersects is utilizing the spatial index and that would be pretty much the same operation also for the simplified geometries. The possible speed-up would come from testing the candidate features and then operation with less vertices is faster. If the envelope is small there are not so mady candidates to test.

What does a explain analyze currently look like?

st_segmentize() all the things

TL;DR: It does help, but you can do better.

Does ST_Simplify() help on lines?
Would the query perform better(...)?

It typically improves performance on all geometries that can vary in number of vertices: simplification reduces their number, and less data to process means faster processing. In some cases it might reduce the bounding box size, too, which also speeds up the index scan.

Is that the usual practice for queries performance fine tuning?

I doubt it is anyone's first or only pick. If you have the time and space to write another column, you can just as well accommodate everything below. Most of that costs no additional space (might even release some), and if you have time to pre-process the whole table constructing the simplified column, then indexing it, I would assume you might be interested in these as well.
create table your_table_backup as table your_table;
drop table your_table;
create table your_table as 
    select * from your_table_backup 
    limit 0;
--alter table your_table --the two below don't work together, pick one
  --  alter column geom set storage external;--costs space, saves CPU
  ----alter column geom set compression lz4;--might save space and (some) CPU
insert into your_table 
    select * from your_table_backup 
    order by random();
create extension if not exists btree_gist;
create index idx1 on your_table 
    using gist(category, --categories become level 1 index nodes
               geom)     --each category "gets its own R-tree"
    include(id,name)     --inert values you don't filter on, as payload
    with(fillfactor=100) --pack it tight
    where class in ('c1','c3');

cluster verbose your_table using idx1;
analyze your_table;


Re-write the table with order by random(), before building the index. You'll get a prettier tree, and those are faster to climb.

Set up the R-Tree-over-GiST index:

If the table is static, use fillfactor=100. The default is 90 to accommodate updates/inserts without immediately having to set up new pages. Smaller, more tightly packed index is faster to process.
If there are other columns you're filtering on, consider making it a partial index. That further reduces its size and increases its performance. Also, the where condition that fully matches the predicate costs nothing, since the index is now pre-filtered to match.
If it's hard to rewrite your other where or join conditions into a partial index predicate, consider BTree_GiST extension that will let you mix in non-geometry columns into the same index. Hard meaning there's variability, ranges, similarities, easy meaning some static filtering, like a predefined set of specific values.
Given few enough, small enough columns in your select list, consider adding them to the index as payload using the include clause. That way you might get way faster Index-Only Scans, where the db doesn't have to fetch anything from the actual table, because all requested info is found right in the index it's reading anyway.
If the columns you request don't fit in an index and you expect to always require some heap fetches, cluster the table so that it's re-arranged to follow the order of the index. That simplifies the jump from the index to the table (illustrated here). You can keep it clustered regardless - it costs some time to re-write (plus 2x space but only for the time it's being re-written), but otherwise it's free. That's again best for static tables, because traffic on the table requires that you either lower the table's fillfactor to leave room for future inserts, or re-run cluster after you apply a big update, or every now and then if you get constant traffic of smaller ones - to apply that order to new values.


If the performance isn't satisfactory yet, you can also tweak storage mode and/or compression methods.

Check how your geometries are stored in terms of the storage mode. Default setting of extended means some will be stored in-line, some compressed, some moved to TOAST, some moved out and compressed. Switching everything to external (out of line, uncompressed) can improve the processing performance of datasets that are dominated by complex shapes.
The obvious expense is storage space, but your queries get faster
simply because they don't need to decompress data before processing
it.
If you can't afford the space, you can alter table your_table alter column geom set compression lz4; or just set default_toast_compression='lz4'; from the usual pglz. Different compression methods can potentially offer higher compression ratios and/or quicker decompression times, both of which contribute to performance of queries that'll need to read less, and decompress that quicker. Addition of zstd and more is being discussed here and here.


If at this stage you're still not satisfied, you can do your thing with ST_Simplify(). But there's another, lossless method of vertex count reduction in lines: ST_Segmentize(). Sub-segments of lines are simpler just because each only represents a subset of the overall geom vertices, but their combination still represents the true shape, which isn't the case with ST_Simplify()-ied geoms. What's more important, bounding boxes of segments are smaller. This means the index search gets more effective, and the final comparison gets faster. The segments that are further away from your tile get skipped and the segments that are nearer, are easier to compare thanks to decreased vertex count.
create table your_table_segments as 
select id,(st_dump(st_segmentize(geom,50))).geom 
from your_table;

create index on your_table_segments using gist(id,geom);
analyze your_table_segments;

It densifies the geometry a bit: points where sub-segments are split increase the total vertex count (unless they end up perfectly on pre-existing vertices), but the increase in index search performance thanks to smaller bounding boxes, typically more than compensates for that. There's also a way to cut them up without adding any vertices:
create table your_table_segments as 
select id,st_union(segment_geom) 
from your_table 
cross join lateral--or just a `,`
     st_dumpsegments(geom) with ordinality as dp(path,segment_geom,seg_num)
group by id, seg_num::int/5;--split on every 5 vertices

ST_Segmentize() splits every X meters, while the above splits every X vertices, without adding extra, but the resulting bounding box sizes are dictated by how dense the input line was to begin with.

You can normally ST_Subdivide() the polygons on the other side of the join to double the effect but in case of your perfectly rectangular envelopes, that's not necessary.


The last two ideas require that you change your query slightly. This:
select t1.id,t1.name,t1.category 
from your_table t1
join your_tiles t2 
  on t2.id=9
 and st_intersects(t1.geom,t2.envelope);

Becomes this:
select id,name,category 
from your_table t1
where exists (
    select 
      from your_table_segments t2 
      join your_tiles t3
        on t3.id=9
       and t2.id=t1.id
       and st_intersects(t2.geom,t3.envelope)
);

Depending on the details of your current query, you can express that in different ways as using exists/in/join/"anti-join".

Apologies for the wall of text. I'm a bit short on time, but once things relax a bit I'll try to add a demo with benchmarks and shorten this a bit. For now, you'll have to trust the sources I linked.

This is far more than I expected. Thank yoi so much for the effort! I am reading it a couple of times. Some things are clear, some I am not familiar with. Let me go through them a bit more and I might come with some question if I cannot clear them myself.

My table is not static, data is constantly being added. Having that on mind, should order by random() be a part of regular index rebuilding routine or is it a one time thing that should be done only initially?

The point of that randomisation is to affect the index build. If you don't cluster, the data in the table remains as it was but your delta, the new rows added since the randomised re-write, aren't stirred as well as the rest. If you later cluster the table, that one step undoes the whole mixing thing, so you do have to re-randomise the whole thing again before you refresh the index, then cluster again based on that fresh index.

If constantly really means constantly, then that also limits your mileage with cluster and tweaking table and index fillfactor settings, but both are still worth looking into - cluster helps even if some time had passed since the last re-write, and if your table grows more than 10% in between "refreshes", you might want to actually reduce the fillfactor further. With cluster applied, it makes sense to reduce table's default 100 so that new rows slide into empty slots, following cluster order, as opposed to being redirected to new pages that don't follow that order.

I have other WHERE clauses that get that same data by other columns. They are equally important in terms of usage so I am a bit undecisive about clustering. Only if I split table in terms to extract geometry and id into a separate table and cluster that by gist index. That might work because once I filter by ST_Intersect, the result set will be small enough that subsequent JOIN to get all attributes would be negligible.

Question is: is performance gained by cluster worth splitting the table?
